# React Redux - Get value of Redux state and update local state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code that updates the state. I am storing values of mandatory fields in - `mandatory_fields`

```
class CompleteProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    completeProfileNeeded: false,
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let { dispatch, session } = this.props
    dispatch(getMandatoryFields(session.username))
  }
```

The Redux state is updated as shown below using `dispatch(getMandatoryFields(session.username))`

[image]

My mapstatetoprops is :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  mandatory_fields: state.User.mandatory_fields,
  session: state.User.session,
})
```

How can I get the value of gender, religion and age from `mandatory_fields` and if they have no value as shown above, update `completeProfileNeeded: true`

Comment: You need to dispatch another action, which will update reducer with new information.

Comment: Your code doesn't seems to need state. Everything seems to be computable in mapState.

Answer (score 0):

Values are `mapped from state to props`, `gender` will be under `this.props.mandatory_fields.gender`.

You can use componentDidUpdate to check if values are defined and update state but this has to be conditional action to prevent loop.

As Mas stated it (`completeProfileNeeded`) can be computed in map state and passed with other values.

You can also directly use some (or all) of these values in conditional rendering without setting this as value in state.

Comment: Thanks. I change code to be computing completeProfileNeeded right where I am getting values from database. That way my payload only has `completeProfileNeeded true/false`. This state in redux is getting update fine but `this.props.mandatory_fields.completeProfileNeeded` is always `true`. I was expecting it to be true only if redux state is true.

Comment: not updating `mapStateToProps`? under/inside `mandatory_fields` like `gender`? make it separate value, redux may not react to deeper changes